# Convergence of Power Series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I am working on some online calc2 homework problems on power series and I am completely confused on how to solve these types of questions. I thought the correct answer would be infinity because I think the series converges for all values of X, but I was wrong and I realized that I really do not know how to begin to tackle this problem. So if someone has a free minute to help me out I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enter it in interval form ie. $[-\infty,\infty]$. Your answer is right, because n! is way larger than exponential.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me enter the correct interval!

Comment: What's up with the brackets? Aren't they supposed to be both open? Also, one's bold while the other's narrow. O_o Thumbs down!